# Custom activity feed notifications, WebUrl does not navigate to tab on selecting the notification, for iOS

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, teams-toolkit

I successfully implemented custom notifications for teams. On click of notification it navigates to a tab in our application (we set tab deep link in `TeamworkActivityTopic.WebUrl`). It works fine on desktop app, browser and android mobile app too.

For iOS, it shows the notification in activity feed, but on selecting it, it does nothing, for same user and for same notification. It is supposed to navigate to a tab in our Teams app. Is it a known issue or work still in progress for iOS regarding this?

Code is similar to "Example 3: Notify a user about an event using a custom topic": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-send-activityfeednotifications#example-3-notify-a-user-about-an-event-using-a-custom-topic

**UPDATE [18 March 2022]**: Now we do not even receive Activity feed notification on Android and iPhone. Desktop app is working fine. Below is the Graph API call we make to send a notification.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/bad19d24-****-****-b624-f577bf9bcfe6/microsoft.graph.sendActivityNotification HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.microsoft.com
SdkVersion: Graph-dotnet-2.0.5
FeatureFlag: 0000004F
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAi***
Accept-Encoding: gzip
traceparent: 00-03eb336f8d51df4481069de18a606d76-34336682b3fbf74f-00
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 554
 
{"topic":{"source":"text","value":"Regarding: Regarding: Reference number 434232","webUrl":"https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/ff5b7b81-ef94-441d-bc7c-eb04e53a188f/01e9900e-75a1-4355-906a-4eda1f5df5ca?context={\u0022subEntityId\u0022:\u0022b6cf5291-8115-4640-8f12-f6a29bb02280\u0022}"},"activityType":"callerInfo","templateParameters":[{"name":"callerName","value":"Ajinkya Shidhore"},{"name":"company","value":"My Company"}],"recipient":{"userId":"a3ca1d30-0b6b-4a6c-9ed6-18be5edcaa07","@odata.type":"microsoft.graph.aadUserNotificationRecipient"}}
```

Comment: Could you please share which sample you are referring?

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT I am referring to "Example 3: Notify a user about an event using a custom topic": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-send-activityfeednotifications#example-3-notify-a-user-about-an-event-using-a-custom-topic

We are setting tab deep link in `TeamworkActivityTopic.WebUrl`

Comment: We tried to repro your issue. We have implemented custom notifications for teams. Create tab deep link in TeamworkActivityTopic.WebUrl. We have tested on desktop,web,android and IOS client.  But its working fine at our end. We have tested on IOS 15.1.1 and Teams version 3.20.0. Could you please try to update Teams version in IOS and check again.

Comment: Could you please confirm is your issue resolved or still facing the issue?

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT Are you using published Teams custom app? We still get the issue for iOS 15.2 and Teams 3.22 version. Microsoft says that it will get resolved once our Teams app is published to store. I will inform once our App is published. Thanks!

Comment: We are not using published Teams custom app.

Comment: Could you please confirm is your issue resolved or still facing the issue?

Comment: I will inform once our App is published. Mostly in a day or two.

Comment: Could you please confirm is your issue resolved or still facing the issue?

Comment: We are still facing issue.

Comment: Could you please share error screenshots and error log file?

Comment: Could you please share the screenshots and error that you are facing?

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT My bad, the app is not yet approved by Microsoft for Mobile clients. I will let you know once it is approved.

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT Today Microsoft has replied that they have whitelisted our app for Mobile clients. Now we can see the app on Mobile.
Activity Feed notification does not work for Mobile clients. Earlier, the mobile clients at least used to receive the notification, but now there is not notification at all. Everything works on Desktop app for same Teams user.

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT we do not have any error log or screenshot as it is failing on Microsoft Graph API side. Activity Feed notification is not visible on Android and iPhone both. Will update the question with Graph api call details.

Comment: @ajinkyashidhore - Again we checked using nodejs sample(https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/graph-activity-feed/nodejs) and were getting notification in Android. Please take up the latest code as its last updated in January