# Microsoft Graph API Activity Feeds Notification does not push to mobile app

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm **POST**-ing to MS Teams Activity Feed Notifications via the Microsoft Graph API. However, the notifications are only being pushed through to the **desktop** and **browser** applications

With the Microsoft Teams Mobile Application (both Android and iOS),  we are getting either none, or intermittent push notifications, and the mobile Activity Feed is not showing any of our notification items.

I am using the following endpoint:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{GROUP_ID}/sendActivityNotification`

I have the following payload:

```json
{
    "topic": {
        "source": "text",
        "value": "Relevant Channel",
        "webUrl": "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/{APP_ID}/{ENTITY_ID}?context={\"channelId\":\"{CHANNEL_ID}\"}"
    },
    "activityType": "userMention",
    "previewText": {
        "content": "App Name"
    },
    "recipient": {
        "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.aadUserNotificationRecipient",
        "userId": "{RECIPIENT_AADOBJECTID}"
    },
    "templateParameters": [
        {
            "name": "name",
            "value": "My Name"
        }
    ]
}
```

My authentication token is fine, and included in the headers, and my application has all the required permissions.

---

Am I posting to the wrong endpoint, or are there issues around push notifications to the Microsoft Teams application on mobile devices?

Comment: Could you please follow this sample and check if it works? https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/graph-activity-feed/csharp

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT The sample is useless to me as we are not using c#

Comment: It appears that this is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70669268/custom-activity-feed-notifications-weburl-does-not-navigate-to-tab-on-selecting) - see the **18th March 2022** update and the discussion

Comment: We checked using nodejs sample(https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/graph-activity-feed/nodejs) and were getting notification in Android. Please take up the latest code as its last updated in January

Answer (score 0):

We followed this sample (https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/graph-activity-feed/nodejs) and were able to get activity feed notification in both MS Teams Desktop, Web and mobile client.

*MS Teams Version(Android): 1416/1.0.0.2022262002/0313*

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/xxxxb29b-2dde-4682-xxxx-4ec85e5bxxxx/sendActivityNotification

{
    "topic": {
        "source": "entityUrl",
        "value": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/xxxxb29b-2dde-4682-xxxx-4ec85e5bxxxx"
    },
    "activityType": "pendingFinanceApprovalRequests",
    "previewText": {
        "content": "Internal spending team has a pending finance approval requests"
    },
    "recipient": {
        "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.aadUserNotificationRecipient",
        "userId": "xxxx3913-2766-4e6f-9edb-90d52bfxxxxx"
    },
    "templateParameters": [
        {
            "name": "pendingRequestCount",
            "value": "5"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Prasad - Could you test with "topic" > "source" being "text" (like ours). And also the "activityType" being "userMention" ?

Comment: Yes, we again tested as you mentioned, and were able to get activity feed notification in both MS Teams Desktop, Web and mobile client.